# noindentafter with and without empty line

Tags: environments, indentation, noindentafter

From what I read I had thought that the package [noindentafter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter) would reliably get rid of any indent after an environment no matter if followed or not by an empty line, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/reliable-code-for-automatic-noindent-after-specific-environments).
But consider this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{newenv}{}{%
%\ignorespacesafterend\noindent% << OPTION 2
} 
\usepackage{noindentafter}\NoIndentAfterEnv{newenv} % OPTION 1

\begin{document}

\begin{newenv} % First Sequence

\lipsum[6]

\end{newenv}

\lipsum[7-8]

\begin{newenv} % Second Sequence
\lipsum[6]
\end{newenv}
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

Using `noindentafter` works for the first sequence, but not for the second where I have left no line after `\end{newenv}`. Now I've tried to not use the package and do it manually with what I've labeled option 2 above (outcommenting option 1). This works for the second scenario but not for the first. I have further tried to use both together (leaving both options uncommented), which gives the weird result that while in the second scenario it's fine, in the first scenario I now get the first *and second* paragraphs after the environment with no indent.

From the package documentation and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/reliable-code-for-automatic-noindent-after-specific-environments) and the ones referred to in there I couldn't figure out what could be wrong here. (Other than me leaving or not an empty line, but I am trying to find a stable solution since the particular environment I'm working on gets `\input` from other files where I can never be sure if they end or do not end with an empty line.)

Comment: Blank lines have a semantic value. Trying to modify it is bound to give you any sort of problem.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, but is there a way to make it behave differently whether or not there is an empty line after that particular enviroment?

Comment: The code of `noindentafter` checks *whether it is followed by a paragraph*, which means it doesn't do anything if there is no empty line after the environment. You will have to patch `\NoIndentAfterEnv` to insert some \par if you want to change this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, I see, but if it checks whether it is followed by a paragraph, why do I get noindent in the _second_ paragraph if I use both of the above options together?

Comment: noindentafter redefines temporarly \par and restore it later, but as it doesn't insert a \par and so actually suppress one \par in the process and so the \noindent is used for the second paragraph. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268532/why-does-noindentafter-package-cause-this-behavior/268537#268537

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm, I still don't seem to get it. The solution in the question you refer to still doesn't solve the second scenario. I've also tried putting a `\par` after the environment but to no avail.

Comment: Note: the `noindentafter` package is broken with the latest latex version (may 2021), seems it has been broken since nov 2019. See [this github issue](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-noindentafter/pull/3) and [this SE TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514127/incompatibility-between-noindentafter-and-etoolbox-v2-5f) question for details and potential solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want always to start a new paragraph after your environment you could do this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{noindentafter}

\newenvironment{newenv}{}{\par} %\par!
\NoIndentAfterEnv{newenv} 
\makeatletter
\appto\@noindent@newenv@hook{\par}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
normal indent

\begin{newenv} 

in env

\end{newenv}

after env \par after env

\begin{newenv} 
in env
\end{newenv}
after env \par after env
\end{document}
```

[image]