# Incompatibility between noindentafter and etoolbox (> v2.5f)?

Tags: etoolbox, noindentafter

After compilation of some legacy code including the `noindentafter` package, I just noticed that they produce a warning which never came up before:

> ```
> Package noindentafter Warning: Patching `\end' failed!
> (noindentafter)                `\NoIndentAfter...' commands won't work.
> ```

I think this message is the result of an update of the `etoolbox` package (which is used in `noindentafter`) since its revision history notes say:

> 2.5g 2019-09-09 Update patching of `\begin` and `\end` in advance of LaTeX kernel changes

Perhaps that patch has given rise to some incompatibility with `noindentafter`. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}% % To make the indentation clearly visible 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(1)]  Some text.
\item[(2)]  Some other text.
\end{enumerate}

Text that should not be indented.
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Any hint is welcome!

Comment: It's not `etoolbox`, but `noindentafter` that tries patching `\end` (which is a bad thing to do, IMHO), but `\end` has changed.

Comment: Here's the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-noindentafter/pull/3), with a patch and a pull request (not yet accepted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `noindentafter` wants to patch `\end` (which is a bad thing to do), in order to inject some code. With the last release of LaTeX, `\end` has become robust, but in a rather peculiar way that makes `xpatch` useless in this case.

The package should do

```latex
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname end \endcsname{%
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi%
}{%
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi%
  \csuse{@noindent@#1@hook}%
}{}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{noindentafter}{%
    Patching `\string\end' failed!\MessageBreak%
    `\string\NoIndentAfter...' commands won't work%
  }%
}
```

You can do it yourself, but you have to live with the innocuous warning until the package is updated.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}% % To make the indentation clearly visible 

\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname end \endcsname{%
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi%
}{%
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi%
  \csuse{@noindent@#1@hook}%
}{}{%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{noindentafter}{%
    Patching `\string\end' failed!\MessageBreak%
    `\string\NoIndentAfter...' commands won't work%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(1)]  Some text.
\item[(2)]  Some other text.
\end{enumerate}

Text that should not be indented.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure about the usefulness of the package, as it's much easier not to leave a blank line after `\end{enumerate}` and obtain exactly the same output.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}% % To make the indentation clearly visible

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(1)]  Some text.
\item[(2)]  Some other text.
\end{enumerate}
Text that should not be indented.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation. I actually find the package quite useful because it provides a generic way to suppress indentations after certain (types of) environments -- which protects against local input errors. I have brought the problem to the attention of the author of noindentafter, so hopefully there will be an update of the package.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for this! I haven't used LaTeX for quite a while, so I haven't been keeping up to date. - As for the wisdom of patching `\end`, I agree, and your point is demonstrated by this very bug. :-) But I don't know a clean way to achieve the same result, and I do think the package is useful. At least for us folks who like to separate formatting from content.

Comment: @mhelvens You could do the fix and declare the package “no longer maintained”

Comment: Agreeing with egreg. @mhelvens: the package is broken since two years and is still on CTAN. There's also [pull requests at your repo](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-noindentafter/pull/4) (un-accepted, un-commented) since some time, allegedly (I haven't tested myself) fixing the issues. Please at least take some actions to have it removed from CTAN, if nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that its not necessary anymore to patch `\end` directly. The `etoolbox`-macro `\AfterEndEnvironment` can do the very same now. The following code works for me, copied from the `noindentafter`-package.

```
\newcommand*\@NoIndentAfter{%
    \@ifnextchar\par{%
        \def\par{%
            \everypar{\setbox\z@\lastbox\everypar{}}%
            \@restorepar%
        }%
    }{}%
}
\newrobustcmd*{\NoIndentAfterThis}{\@NoIndentAfter\par\par}

\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\NoIndentAfterThis}
```

I assume this works only for the *updated* version of `\end` (see [@egregs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514132/77563) about the update), because the `noindentafter` package author explicitely writes:

> The package `etoolbox` provides the command `\AfterEndEnvironment` which creates a hook executed at a very late point inside the `\end` command. However, this
>   hook is still located before `\ignorespaces`, which is too early to properly suppress
>   the indention after an environment. Therefore another hook is now added to `\end`
>   using `\patchcmd`. This new hook puts new code at the very end.

However, this doesn't seem to be true anymore.

Comment: I did write an email to the package author about this. Maybe we see a fix in the package soon.