# Suppress parindent after list environments

Tags: lists, indentation

I learned that the reason for parindents is to provide visual clues for paragraph ends. According to some people, is [an error to use both `\parindent` and `\parskip`](https://practicaltypography.com/first-line-indents.html).

Thinking about this, the logical consequence is that:

1. it is an error to indent the first paragraph in a section (TeX handles this nicely)
2. it is also an error to indent after vertical space

While point 2 should be prevented by not using a parskip, it is not prevented after using a list environment such as `itemize`. It looks odd to me to indent a paragraph after a list.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}

    \lipsum

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum
    \end{itemize}

    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

## Can I generally prevent an `\indent` after certain environments?

I know I can prevent the indent with `\noindent`. I also know I can prevent the indent by not leaving a blank line in the tex file:

```
\lipsum
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum
\end{itemize}
%
\lipsum
```

But in my understanding, it should be possible to redefine the `itemize` environment to prevent this indent in general.
The `section` command *does* somehow prevent the first paragraph indent, after all.

Comment: Section and envs are very different, the grouping in envs makes it very hard to add a "no indent after env even if there are blank lines" feature.

Comment: If you don't want indentation after `enumerate`, just leave no blank line.

Comment: @egreg This is not a solution. I want it to work consistently, not by manually "fixing" the source and hoping I dont miss it anywhere.

Comment: @Qw3ry Where's the inconsistency? If you want no indent, no blank line; if you want a new (indented) paragraph, add a blank line. I think that getting the same behavior with or without a blank line is inconsistent.

Comment: @egreg the incosistency is in the resulting document, with _some_ paragraphs indented, and others not. I want to make sure that the resulting document has consistent formatting

Comment: @Qw3ry The indentation denotes a new paragraph. It can be needed after a list or not, depending on the text that follows the list. You're making life more difficult to your readers if you unconditionally avoid indentation.

Comment: @egreg can you make an example? Off the top of my head I cannot think of one. Are there any typographic rules regarding this specific problem?

Comment: @Qw3ry -- You've asked for an example where a new paragraph following a list *should* be indented.  This example, found by a semi-random review of TUGboat articles, starts a completely new topic, and indentation is essential: [from TUGboat 39:3](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-3/tb123schubotz-mathtext.pdf); see section 3 on the 5th page (p.232).

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the question, I believe that the vertical space is enough to start a new paragraph visually. The indentation looks odd to me. Of course it will disallow to not start a new paragraph after a list, which is kind of impractical. But from visual guideance, it is always there. That's why I ask for typographic rules for this very situation.

Comment: I figured that it is probably another question whether to put an indent or not, so I [asked it separately](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/130997/145373)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, I did not find anything while googling for an answer, but I found the [`noindentafter`](https://ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter) package, while trying to tag my question with something like `noindent`. So [I decided to ask it anyway and provide an answer by myself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

The following lines in the preamble do the trick for me:

```
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{itemize}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}
```

Edit: As the `noindentafter` package stopped working with up-to-date versions of `etoolbox`, I found it pretty easy to [achieve this without the package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515465/77563)

Comment: that is a very dangerous package as it messes with `\end`

Comment: @daleif why is it dangerous? What does it exactly do and what can break if I use it?

Comment: Well, for one, it does not compile on an up to date LaTeX installation as `\end` was changed in the latex kernel.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. Still, I got the impression this fragility is there for a lot of packages, and is rather an issue of how LaTeX works in general.

Comment: Any alternative?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515465/77563)